# Code save in Java

Tags: java, swing

I use Application simple Form in Java. I have the code like this.

```
Graphics g = null;
Graphics g1;
boolean conPaint, temp = false;
int x, y;
BufferedImage img;
public project() {
    initComponents();
    super.paintComponents(g);
    img = new BufferedImage(1366 , 768,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g = img.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g1 = getGraphics();
    conPaint = false;
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    fileMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    openMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    saveMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    exitMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    editMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    cutMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    copyMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    pasteMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    deleteMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    helpMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    contentsMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    aboutMenuItem = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setToolTipText("");
    jLabel1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel1MouseEntered(evt);
        }
    });
    jLabel1.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel1MouseDragged(evt);
        }
        public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jLabel1MouseMoved(evt);
        }
    });

    fileMenu.setMnemonic('f');
    fileMenu.setText("File");

    openMenuItem.setMnemonic('o');
    openMenuItem.setText("Open");
    openMenuItem.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            openMenuItemActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);

    saveMenuItem.setMnemonic('s');
    saveMenuItem.setText("Save");
    saveMenuItem.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            saveMenuItemActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    fileMenu.add(saveMenuItem);

    exitMenuItem.setMnemonic('x');
    exitMenuItem.setText("Exit");
    exitMenuItem.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            exitMenuItemActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);

    menuBar.add(fileMenu);

    editMenu.setMnemonic('e');
    editMenu.setText("Edit");

    cutMenuItem.setMnemonic('t');
    cutMenuItem.setText("Cut");
    editMenu.add(cutMenuItem);

    copyMenuItem.setMnemonic('y');
    copyMenuItem.setText("Copy");
    editMenu.add(copyMenuItem);

    pasteMenuItem.setMnemonic('p');
    pasteMenuItem.setText("Paste");
    editMenu.add(pasteMenuItem);

    deleteMenuItem.setMnemonic('d');
    deleteMenuItem.setText("Delete");
    editMenu.add(deleteMenuItem);

    menuBar.add(editMenu);

    helpMenu.setMnemonic('h');
    helpMenu.setText("Help");

    contentsMenuItem.setMnemonic('c');
    contentsMenuItem.setText("Contents");
    helpMenu.add(contentsMenuItem);

    aboutMenuItem.setMnemonic('a');
    aboutMenuItem.setText("About");
    helpMenu.add(aboutMenuItem);

    menuBar.add(helpMenu);

    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void exitMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    System.exit(0);
}                                            

private void openMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter ff = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.jpg *.png *.jpeg *.gif *.bmp files", "jpg", "png","jpeg","gif","bmp");
    chooser.setFileFilter(ff);
    chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    File linkimage = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(linkimage.getPath());
    jLabel1.setSize( 1366 , 768);
    jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
    Graphics2D gr2d = img.createGraphics();
    jLabel1.paint(gr2d);
}                                            

private void saveMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    JFileChooser jFile = new JFileChooser();
    jFile.showSaveDialog(null);
    Path pth = jFile.getSelectedFile().toPath();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Save Completed!!!");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File(pth.toString()));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}                                            

private void jLabel1MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    if (temp)
    {
    if (conPaint)
    g.drawLine(x, y, evt.getX(), evt.getY());
    g1.drawLine(x + 8, y + 53, evt.getX() + 8, evt.getY() + 53);
    x = evt.getX();
    y = evt.getY();
    }
}                                    
private void jLabel1MouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
    if (temp)
    {
    conPaint = true;
    x = evt.getX();
    y = evt.getY();
    }
}                                  

private void jLabel1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    temp = true;
}
```

There are 2 problem:

1. When it is finished, save the image background color is black, how to make it white.
2. When mouse drag out `jLabel`, how it did not draw this.

Comment: Your English isn't easy to understand. What is `Application simple Form`? Q1: When it is finished - what is "it"? If you don't save the backgroundcolor, it isn't black? Make it white before saving or after saving? Q2: "how it did not draw this" - what is "this"? What "it"? Isn't the jLabel drawn? The mouse? Btw.: a) Using imports makes the code much more readable. b) A compileable, runnable Code would be much better, reduced to just the problematic phaenomen (background, jLable) even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set your background color:
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

As for the second question, are you sure you set both temp and conPaint to true before dragging? Make sure MouseEntered is called before MouseMoved, which should be called earlier than MouseDragged. Otherwise it will not work at all (first you need temp to be true, then conPaint and only then MouseDragged is going to work. Are you sure you need such a complex logic to it? Do you really need temp and conPaint variables?)

And for future: add some proper tabulation to your code to make it readeble.